# Missing required parameters for [Route: Kategori.destroy] [URI: Model/Kategori/{Kategori}]

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

`<a href="{{ route('Kategori.edit', $d->id) }}" class="dropdown-item">Edit</a> <a href="{{ route('Kategori.destroy', $d->id) }}" class="dropdown-item">Delete</a>`

this was successful on edit but not on destroy

I use the resource route all sections are successful only on route Category.destroy this is not successful. after I overcome the white screen appears

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show some code so other may get a better idea.

Comment: <a href="{{ route('Kategori.edit', $d->id) }}" class="dropdown-item">Edit</a>
                            <a href="/Model/Kategori/{{ Kategori.destroy, $d->id }}" class="dropdown-item delete-record">Delete</a></div></div>

Comment: You should edit the question and add this there

Comment: You should provide model, controller and view code in this question to help us to understand your question. In feature try to do it with every question related to laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete should be a form submit assuming you are using HTTP `DELETE` for the route:

```html
<form action="{{ route('Kategori.destroy', $d->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')

    <button type="submit">
        Delete
    </button>
</form>
```